# Standard notation for crossings (female, male)

Tags: genetics, hybridization

Is there any standard for the notation of a crossing (hybrid) which tells me which part is the mother and which is the father?

Example
`StrainA`: egg cell
`StrainB`: sperm cell

Which notation is correct?
`StrainA x StrainB` or
`StrainB x StrainA`
or isn't there a rule for this?

Answer (score -1):

For plants, seed (egg cell) parent is shown first and pollen (sperm) parent second.

The rule is mentioned in wikipedia,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_(biology)

section : in plants.

Another mention of plant example:

https://www.rhododendron.org/v50n1p36.htm

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a scientific reference for this?